# Regex for validate string, date format YYYYMMDD without separators + 5 free Digits

Tags: java, regex, validation, date-parsing

**I need to use a regex to validate the next rules :**

•The first 8 characters should be in ‘date’ format of YYYYMMDD without 
 separators

•Total expression length should be 13 characters

I use internal regular expressions manager

**Java code example :**

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

```
public class TestDate {
  public static final Pattern datePattern = Pattern.compile("** Need RegEx **");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(datePattern.matcher("1996022965789").matches()); 
// -Wrong value 
 System.out.println(datePattern.matcher("1996022865789").matches()); 
// -Correct value 
  }
}
```

Examples for input values and expected results :

**Input**: 201909866666 **Result**: Wrong Length

**Input**: 2019022966666 **Result**: Wrong date value

**Input**: 2019022866666 **Result**: correct

Comment: Did you tried some regex yourself? Do you want to differentiate between "Wrong Length" and "Wrong date value", because your code has only two states - ok or wrong? Also I do not think regular expression is able to know when 29th February is ok or not, you will need to use some date API to check it.

Comment: You can try site like [regxr](https://regexr.com/) to visually see the matching pattern while, trying to form regular expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Don’t use a regular expression for validating a date. It’ll be much too complicated. Use `LocalDate` and a `DateTimeFormatter` for validating the date and possibly a regular expression for the last 5 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use a regular expression for validating a date. It’ll be much too complicated. Use `LocalDate` and a `DateTimeFormatter`. Here’s a solution that doesn’t use any regular expression at all. You may also use a regular expression for checking that the 5 characters after the date are digits if you prefer.

```
public void testDate(String dateString) {
    if (dateString.length() == 13) {
        // Check date part, first 8 digits
        try {
            LocalDate.parse(dateString.substring(0, 8), DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
            boolean allDigits = dateString.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit);
            if (allDigits) {
                System.out.println(dateString + ": correct");
            } else {
                System.out.println(dateString + ": wrong character, must be digits");
            }
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
            System.out.println(dateString + ": invalid date value");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(dateString + ": wrong length");
    }
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    testDate("1996022965789");
    testDate("1996022865789");
    testDate("201909866666");
    testDate("2019022966666");
```

Output is:

> ```
> 1996022965789: correct
> 1996022865789: correct
> 201909866666: wrong length
> 2019022966666: invalid date value
> ```

For the first result, 1996 was a leap year, so February 29 did exist that year. The last result shows invalid date value because 2019 is not a leap year.

`LocalDate.parse` throws a `DateTimeParseException` if the date is invalid, which we catch and use for printing the correct message in this case. You may polish the messages if you like; as they stand, they may be too short and not very user-friendly.